# Display a selected radio button from database c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, radio-button

Please how can i display a selected radio button according to the value in the database ? example: i want to display the details of an employee with gender value (if the employee have "male" gender in the database i want that the radio button "Male" be selected automatically )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works succesfully for me, i just use a datagridview to compare the value from the database and the value of the radio button.

```
 GridView grid = new GridView();
    grid.ShowDialog(); 
if (grid.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString()=="Male")
{male_radiobtn.Checked=true;
female_radiobtn.Checked=false;}
else {female_radiobtn.Checked=true;
male_radiobtn.Checked=false;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WPF, you can set a boolean property representing male gender. Then bind it to the radio button checked attribute.

In that way if male gender property returns true , the radio button will be checked.

Here is a good example:

[Binding radio button](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720497/Binding-Radio-Buttons-to-a-Single-Property)

You can also use dependency property for this concept but I think the first method will work for you for sure.

Comment: @leila.net you can use the following link to use same notion on win form
[RadioButton binding in Windows Forms with INotifyPropertyChanged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264860/radiobutton-binding-in-windows-forms-with-inotifypropertychanged)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `BindingSource`:

```
BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = (your datasource here, could be a DataSet or an object)

var maleBinding = new Binding("Checked", myBindingSource , "Gender");

maleBinding.Format += (s, args) => args.Value = ((string)args.Value) == "Male";
maleBinding.Parse += (s, args) => args.Value = (bool)args.Value ? "Male" : "Female";

maleRadioButton.DataBindings.Add(maleBinding);

var femaleBinding = new Binding("Checked", myBindingSource , "Gender");

femaleBinding.Format += (s, args) => args.Value = ((string)args.Value) == "Female";
femaleBinding.Parse += (s, args) => args.Value = (bool)args.Value ? "Female" : "Male";

femaleRadioButton.DataBindings.Add(femaleBinding);
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906305/winform-binding-radio-button)

Comment: In the Form Load event.

Answer (score 0):

i have very simple method to display the database data in to the form right here.. i have Student Details database and in this database i have created info table. and i display the info table data.

```
 {
            // this code is to display data from the database table to application 
            int stdid = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text); // convert in to integer to called in sqlcmd
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MILK-THINK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student Details;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select *from info where Student_id=" + stdid,con); // pass the query with connection 
            SqlDataReader dr; // this will read the data from database
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read()==true)
            {
                txtName.Text = dr[1].ToString(); // dr[1] is a colum name which goes in textbox
                cmbCountry.SelectedItem = dr[2].ToString(); // combobox selecteditem will be display
               // for radio button we have to follow this method which in nested if statment
                if(dr[3].ToString()=="Male") 
                {
                    rdbMale.Checked=true;


                }
                else if (dr[3].ToString() == "Female")
                {
                    rdbFemale.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There are no records");
                    dr.Close();
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```